# Columns columns by time in a sql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql table as follows:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| AccountID | PersonId | DoctorID | Admitdatetime |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| 1         | 2        | 345      | 20090108      |
| 2         | 3        | 53       | 20090109      |
| 3         | 1        | 234      | 20090110      |
| 4         | 2        | 345      |               |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Each row of this table is like a visit of a patient given by the `admitdatetime`. Each unique record is referenced by `AccountID`

Date column is basically `int` and is `yyyymmdd`. So just subtracting two dates might not be right as it is not datetime. I just checked.

Now, what I want to do for each record in the table is to add 3 columns. One for last three months, one for last 6 months, and one for last 12 months.

The columns are described as follows: 
The no. of cases a `DoctorID` has seen in the past 3 months of that current record. Similarly, no. of cases a `DoctorID` has seen in the past 6 months of that current record.

I am doing a self join like this:

```
SELECT a.DoctorID, count(AccountID) FROM 
   Visits AS a INNER JOIN 
   Visits AS b ON a.DoctorId = b.DoctorId
WHERE a.admitdatetime - b.admitdatetime <= 90
```

The above one I am doing for the 3 months case, but I don't think it is right. I want for each record the no. of cases (count of `AccountId`) a doctor has seen 3,6,9 months before that. So for each `DoctorID`, that value would vary based on which record the `doctorID` is present and it's 3,6,9 months prior that `admitdatetime` of that record such that the above code would just give me one value for a `doctorID`. That doesn't seem right.

I think the join should be grouped by `DoctorId, AccountId` as I need to join all the `doctorid` back to each record and each record is identified by `accountid`. So then join it back on `doctorid` and `accountid`. Does this sound right?

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your data sample doesnt have `date` also `from 
table Visits as a` have sintaxis error. You cant write `table` there

Comment: That was meant to provide an example. Assume Admitdatetime is a date time value

Comment: You forgot about the pg version.

Comment: Please answer as normal sql irrespective of pg version

Comment: @Manish newer version have better tools and function to solve some problems, so that is why is smart provide version unless you want use older aproach. And if Gordon didnt understand your question maybe you should work a litle bit and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest correlated subqueries:

```
select v.*,
       (select sum(case when v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '3 month'
                        then 1 else 0
                   end)
        from visits v2
        where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid
       ) as last3,
       (select sum(case when v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '6 month'
                        then 1 else 0
                   end)
        from visits v2
        where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid
       ) as last6,
       (select sum(case when v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '12 month'
                        then 1 else 0
                   end)
        from visits v2
        where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid
       ) as last12
from visits v;
```

I should point out that Postgres allows you to simplify this syntax:

```
   (select sum((v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '3 month')::int)
    from visits v2
    where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid
   ) as last3,
```

And in more recent versions of Postgres you can use a `lateral join` to combine the logic into a single subquery.

EDIT:

A reasonable simplification of the query is:

```
select v.*,
       (select count(*)
        from visits v2
        where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid and v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '3 month'
       ) as last3,
       (select count(*)
        from visits v2 
        where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid and 2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '6 month'
       ) as last6,
       (select count(*)
        from visits v2
        where v2.doctorid = v.doctorid and v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '12 month'
       ) as last12
from visits v;
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that it is going to have just one count for a doctorid for these three time frames. But in reality I want for each record and then going back from that record. So a doctorid might be part of two records with two different admit date. so then it would have two values (as long as there are other cases between the two dates) for even 3 month time frame as both the 3 month time frame is starting based on a different admitdate

Comment: @manish . . . That is what these queries do.  Do you understand the condition ` v2.doctorid = v.doctorid and v2.AdmitDate >= v.AdmitDate - interval '12 month'`?

Comment: You are not understanding my point. It would group it by Doctorid. Each doctorid might have different count based on Accountid

Comment: @Manish . . . I repeat.  That is what this query does.  Each row in `visits` should have counts that are reltaive to the dates in that row.  I did just notice that the `from` clauses had some edit junk, which I removed.